# A differentiable function satisfies given conditions. Find the approximated values

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to solve this exercise. I know how to calc a derivatives, directional derivatives, partial derivatives, but I don't know how to solve this exercise.

---

A differentiable function $z = f (x, y)$ satisfies the conditions: $f (1, 2) = 3$, $f_x (1, 2) = 5$ and $f_y(1,2) = 8.$

Calculate the approximate values ​​of $f(1.1,1.8)$ and $f (1.3 , 1.8).$

Thanks!

Comment: ? I don't get it. $f$ is defined on $\Bbb{R}^2$. Why are there four arguments in the question then?

Comment: Anyway, applying definition of derivative, $f(x+h)\approx f(x)+\nabla f (x)\cdot h$, is that what you know?

Comment: I'm sorry! It's a point, not a comma. Can you help me now? Should I have to solve by definition?

Comment: Li Chun Min's answer is what you are looking for. It is a linear approximation extended to more than one dimension.

Comment: In fact, the definition of total derivative at $x$ is really defined using concept of linear approximation. It is defined to be the linear transformation $T_x$ such that $f(x+h) = f(x)+T_x(h)+o(|h|)$. You will learn how to reduce that to my above expression, or expression given by Mr. Potato below, in some rigorous real analysis course.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$f(x+h,y+k)\approx f(x,y)+f_x(x,y)h + f_y(x,y)k $$
Now let $$x=1$$$$y=2$$  $$h=0.1$$ $$k=-0.2$$
This solves the first one. Solve the second one yourself.

Comment: Why h = 0.1 and k = -0.2? thanks